# How to unit test a catch block which does not throw any exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, spock

Here is my code.

```
    @Override
    public KinesisEvent handleRequest(@NonNull KinesisEvent kinesisEvent, @NonNull Context context) {
        KinesisEvent kinesisEventReturn = kinesisEvent.clone();
        final List<KinesisEvent.KinesisEventRecord> transformedRecords = kinesisEventReturn.getRecords().stream().map(
                record -> {
                    try {
                        return decryptLog(record);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.error("Decryption did not work. See exception: ", e);
                    }
                    return record;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        kinesisEventReturn.setRecords(transformedRecords);
        return kinesisEventReturn;
    }
```

If you see, I have catch block which catches exception but not throws the exception. I wanted to test the catch block in unit testing. But all the example i find is to test whether an exception is thrown or not.

Please help if there any work around with that.

Thanks
Dhrubo

Answer (score 1):

Your function steps through a Collection (Stream), attempts to decrypt each record, and produces a list of each decrypted record which it returns.  If the decryption fails, the log message is generated and the original record is added to list instead.

You can use the fact that the if the catch block is exercised, a member of kinesisEventReturn.getRecords() will be on the returned list.  So, your test case requires constructing input known to cause `decryptLog(record)` to throw an `IOException`.

When an `IOException` is thrown/caught, the result of the function will have at least one member from the input `Collection`.  You can use [Collections.disjoint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-) to simplify that test:

```java
if (! Collections.disjoint(result, kinesisEventReturn.getRecords()) {
    // Test failed
```

assuming that decrypted records are always different than encrypted records.

Comment: Would you please mind to elaborate a bit more please. I am newbie with this Java and unit testing :( .

Which result are you telling me to compare with?

Comment: not all decryptLog(record) calls might fail. better check for each record.

Comment: Allen, I upvoted your answer because it is correct and the assert condition is elegant. But the explanation is simply unsuitable for your target audience. The OP himself said that he is a beginner in both Java and testing. Even your previous comment is kind of difficult to read and understand. I recommend you delete the comment, update your question instead and explain at a less technical level. The implicit double negation in `!disjoint(..)` does not make things easier for the OP either. Or you let me edit your question, then we both delete our comments here, shall we?

Comment: OK, I'll give it a shot and look forward to your comment.